# Use hyperlink text as number with gspread/google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

When inserting a link with text in sheets with gspread I insert the following string with valueInputOption 'USER_ENTERED' into the target cell:

```
'=HYPERLINK("' + some_link + '","' + str(some_number) + '")'
```

Because of the python string concatenation, the number has to be cast to a string. In the sheet the number is then handled as a string and not a number and no mathematical functions can be used on this cell.

Is there a way to create a link with gspread whose text can be handled as a number by google sheets?

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this happening?

Comment: A simplification of the Code I use would be:
`cells["A1"].value = '=HYPERLINK("' + "example.com" + '","' + str(42) + '")'
`
While the cell in google sheets shows 42, using =AVG(A1) would result in a #DIV/0! Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
'=HYPERLINK("' + some_link + '","' + str(some_number) + '")'
```

#### To:

```
'=HYPERLINK("' + some_link + '",' + str(some_number) + ')'
```

- By this modification, the double quotes for `str(some_number)` are removed. By this, when `some_number` is `123`, the formula of `=HYPERLINK("some_link",123)` is put to a cell.
- When I check this cell using spreadsheet.get method, I confirmed that `123` is `numberValue` at `effectiveValue`. When your script is used, `123` is `stringValue`.